# Jenkins- Rendering html page in email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, html-email, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

Sending email using Editable Email Notification plugin in Jenkins

[image]

Following is the complete folder structure of the index.html file contains folders related to CCS, styling and images for the html page.
[image]

After receiving a mail- email is not loading image and css contents in email body.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e6]
Not sure how it will get reference to CSS, image and other stylings

Answer (score 0):

For emails to work the CSS has to in-lined first, there are some email clients that don't read CSS in the head of the document.

Here are three resources you can use to inline your CSS:

- [PutsMail (litmus powered)](https://putsmail.com/inliner)
- [CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)
- [CSS inliner](https://inliner.cm/)

Note in order to use these your CSS has to be in the head of the document or it will not work.

That covers the CSS part, now the images. The images have to be loaded to a server and an absolute path has to be referenced in the HTML. If there is a relative path those images will not load.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sorry to say it but can't help if you don't tell us what's wrong and provide code. Read the help center again to see how to ask a question.